# Collect Google Sheets Information Without Authorization

Tags: java, authentication, google-api, google-sheets

How would I go about collecting information correctly off of Google Sheets from a public Google Sheet document without having the user to authenticate anything?

So far, I have the following code I found that looks like it should've done the trick but I get stuck with the

"com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name)"

The following code below generates it, the user login and passwords are correct

```
package streamupdater.util;

import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;


public class readData {

public static final String GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME = "abc"; 
public static final String GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = "xxx"; 

public static final String SPREADSHEET_URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fS0d19BOExTPdWqIYTvD9IskGIYEskqPY0WL9i7FByk/edit#gid=0";



public String getData(){
    String status="";

try{
/** Our view of Google Spreadsheets as an authenticated Google user. */
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Print Google Spreadsheet Demo");

    // Login and prompt the user to pick a sheet to use.
    service.setUserCredentials(GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME,
            GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);

    // Load sheet
    URL metafeedUrl = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);
    SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = service.getEntry(metafeedUrl,SpreadsheetEntry.class);
    URL listFeedUrl = spreadsheet.getWorksheets().get(0).getListFeedUrl();

    // Print entries
    ListFeed feed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);

    for (ListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
        System.out.println("new row");
        for (String tag : entry.getCustomElements().getTags()) {
            System.out.println("     " + tag + ": "
                    + entry.getCustomElements().getValue(tag));
            status=entry.getCustomElements().getValue(tag);

        }
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
System.out.println(status);
return(status);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    readData rd = new readData();
    rd.getData();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a login and password to access private Google data is called client login.  Google Shut down the client login servers in May 2015.  There for your code will not work.    You will need to use Open Authentication.

Suggestions:

1. [Switch to Google Sheets v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/)
2. Try and authenticate with using an API key.  It should give you access to a public Google sheet.  Another less risky thing would be to use a Service account to access a private Google sheet.

Comment: So overall, I still need to authenticate. I'll try a different approach to this, thank you very much. I kind of suspected that authorization would be needed but my other approach will be to read an excel document.

Comment: Google sheets is not an excel document.  When you upload a file to google drive it will be come a google sheets document.   Which you can then use the Google sheets api to access.  You can use an API key or a service account which wont request a users permission to access the file.   But you will still have to register your project on google developers console.

Comment: I kmow about the sheets and excel document, users will have to download their sheet and require it to be an excel document.